# How to I create a remove button on a JavaScript event

Tags: javascript

Below is the js code I'm using to add elements to a TO DO List

```
let addButton = document.getElementById('sub-btn');
let listContainer = document.getElementById('items');
let inputField = document.getElementById('sub');
let rmvButton= document.getElementById('rmv');

//adds items to list after clicking button
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style')
    paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
    listContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = ''
})
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the remove button purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a remove button by simply appending a button with a remove listener.

```js
const remove = document.createElement('button');
remove.textContent = 'Remove';
remove.addEventListener('click', handleRemove);
```

Here is a typical remove handler:

```js
const handleRemove = e => {
  const item = e.target.closest('.item');
  item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
};
```

### Full demo

```js
const addButton = document.getElementById('sub-btn');
const listContainer = document.getElementById('items');
const inputField = document.getElementById('sub');
const rmvButton = document.getElementById('rmv');

const handleRemove = e => {
  const item = e.target.closest('.item');
  
  // Remove the listener, to avoid memory leaks.
  item.querySelector('.remove-btn')
    .removeEventListener('click', handleRemove);
  
  item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
};

// Adds items to list after clicking button
addButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  const paragraph = document.createElement('div');
  const remove = document.createElement('button');
  
  item.classList.add('item');
  paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style');
  remove.classList.add('remove-btn');
  
  paragraph.textContent = inputField.value;
  remove.textContent = 'Remove';
  
  remove.addEventListener('click', handleRemove);
  
  item.append(paragraph);
  item.append(remove);
  listContainer.append(item);
  
  inputField.value = '';
})
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6em;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.667em;
  align-items: center;
}

.paragraph-style {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="sub" />
  <button id="sub-btn">Add</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I already got the CSS part tough, this answer helped me out a lot!

Comment: @KivaGordon Glad to hear. You were really close. As I noted, it is important to detach listeners before you remove elements. It is not so important with smaller applications, but affects much larger applications in the long-run.

Comment: I didn't think about removing the listener before, how would it affect my code if I didn't do it?

Comment: @KivaGordon if you fail to detach listeners, especially if you add over a thousand todos, and then remove them all... there will be a thousand functions hanging out. Similar to dangling pointers. The only way to clean them up is to refresh the page. Too many unused variables/functions increase the application's memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

The exact implementation will depend on which element you want removed, but the general idea is to get a reference to the DOM element, and then call `.remove()` on it.  This example removes the last item in the list, if there is one:

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('sub-btn');
let listContainer = document.getElementById('items');
let inputField = document.getElementById('sub');
let rmvButton= document.getElementById('rmv');

//adds items to list after clicking button
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style')
    paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
    listContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = ''
})

rmvButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const lastItem = listContainer.children[listContainer.children.length-1];
  if (lastItem) {lastItem.remove()}
 })
```

```html
<div id="items">
</div>

<input id="sub" value="item text">

<button id="sub-btn">Add</button>
<button id="rmv">Remove</button>
```

This second example demonstrates how to remove individual items, by attaching a specific remove button to each one as it's generated, with its own click handler:

```js
let addButton = document.getElementById('sub-btn');
let listContainer = document.getElementById('items');
let inputField = document.getElementById('sub');
let rmvButton= document.getElementById('rmv');

//adds items to list after clicking button
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-style')
    paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
    
    // create and append a "remove" button to the item
    var rmv = document.createElement('button');
    rmv.innerText="Remove";
    paragraph.appendChild(rmv);
    
    // add a click handler to it which will remove this specific item, `paragraph`:
    rmv.addEventListener('click', function() {
      paragraph.remove();
    });
    
    listContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = ''
})
```

```html
<div id="items">
</div>

<input id="sub" value="item text">

<button id="sub-btn">Add</button>
```

Comment: Reason for downvote? I'd like to improve the answer if you can tell me what you found less than useful about it.

Comment: Oh, I see, someone downvoted _all_ the answers for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

this removes an element

```
var myobj = document.getElementById("demo");
myobj.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a button the same way you're creating the paragraph element.

```js
// paragraph = ...
// ...
const button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = "Remove"
button.onclick = function() { paragraph.remove() }
// add button to the DOM
```